# Uniqueness of Fourier series in $T\mathbb{H}$

Tags: geometry, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, lie-algebras

> We know that $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})=\langle X,H,W\rangle$ with $$X=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},W=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix},H=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$ As $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})\cong T\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{H\times C}$ one can expand any function $f$ on $T\mathbb{H}$ to a Fourier series in the eigenfunctions of the lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_W$, that is $f=\sum_{k} f_{2k}$.

I'd like to establish some "uniqueness of Fourier series" in this case. Suppose we know $Xf_{2k},Hf_{2k}$ for every $k$ can we find $f$?

Comment: Your $X$ is not a member of $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$. Neither is your $H$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown you're right. Had to be the lie algebra instead (then the trace is $0$).